# Tell VS Code to always use relative paths for TypeScript auto imports?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VS Code is auto-importing everything relative to `baseUrl` using Node-like non-relative paths, which is what I don't want.

How do I tell VS Code to import everything with relative paths (except for Node modules of course)?

Removing the `baseUrl` option is not an option because I need it in order to point `fs` imports at a local polyfill of the `fs` module.

My tsconfig.json has this:

```
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "fs/*": [ "./src/util/FileSystem/*" ]
        }
```

If there's no other way other than removing the `baseUrl` option, then that doesn't do any good!

Comment: Have you tried specifying `"moduleResolution": "node"`? I'm not sure if that will work, but just a suggestion. I've never found it necessary to polyfill a node module like that. If you're in control of the project, why can't you just change the `fs` imports to be relative like the rest? Or if it's just for testing, configure the polyfill through a library like jest instead of the tsconfig file.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hi, thanks, I do have `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To enforce relative path auto imports in VS Code, you can change the [`importModuleSpecifier`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_preferences-for-auto-imports-and-generated-code) setting to value `"relative"`.

settings.json (workspace or user):

```
{
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
  // ...
}
```

The value `"non-relative"` would create absolute paths based on `baseUrl`, `"auto"` ([default setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)) selects the shortest path automatically.

For JavaScript there is an analogue setting `"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier"`.

Comment: The new `project-relative` value is an improvement. It is the same as "relative", unless the import path would navigate beyond the root of the current project. Check it out!